# gazebo actor sdf 1.3 parser error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'been trying to get the actor tag running in the latest gazebo version 1.4. However I've not succeded. I always get the following error:

```
Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.100.1.2

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.100.1.2
Error [SDF.cc:757] Missing element description for [filename]
gazebo: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:424: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = sdf::Element]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:62] escalating to SIGKILL on client
```

The world file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
  <world name="default">
    <!-- A global light source -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>

    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    
            <actor name="actor1" static="true">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <skin>
              <filename> walk.dae </filename>
        </skin>
        </actor>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1538/gazebo-actor-sdf-1.3-parser-error/) by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Here is an example of a world file [actor.world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3b71414a1c761150cc84fda2f2cd9220f9296f64/sdf/worlds/actor.world?at=default) which includes the [actor.model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3b71414a1c76/sdf/models/actor.model?at=default) file (careful that the sdf model is 1.2 for actor.model, but I think you can change it to 1.3). But I don't really see any difference between these files and your world.

Do you have the `walk.dae` file in the `~/.gazebo` folder?

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0